# How do I monitor what my server is downloading? Is there a log of past activity?

Tags: internet, download, windows-server-2008, logging

At work I run a server that connects to the internet using a GSM modem with a monthly download limit of 30Gb. For the past three months we've been going over that limit. The ISP gives us a log of daily total uploads and daily total downloads to the server. We have 3 - 6 days a month where the server is downloading a huge amount of data (sometimes as much as 12Gb).

We do not know what the server is downloading. We've checked the windows update log, and these downloads only coincide with one of the days with a lot of downloading, so can't account for traffic on other days.

We're running Windows server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

Is there a log of what the server has been downloading in the past? Are there any other useful ways of monitoring this?

Comment: Are you going through a router before the modem?

Comment: The server is connected to an Ethernet Switch, and then that is connected to the GSM modem. The modem is a Digi TransPort WR21, I'm not sure what the switch is.

Comment: check your windows updates on every connected pc, it happened to meonce that a update got 'stuck' and always wanted me to reboot / and then again download the KB23xyz...

Comment: I have now enabled something that is called 'Local Logging', but it hasn't produced a log file yet & I'm not sure if it will log what I want it to. There are no PCs connected - there is the server, and then everything else on the network is a data logger, and these can't download anything.